# Covergence of a series implies divergence of another series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that for any non-negative unbounded sequence $\{\beta_n\}$, there exists a non-negative sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\alpha_n}$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\alpha_n \beta_n}$ diverges. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{\beta_k \}$ is unbounded, for each $j \in \mathbb N$, we can find natural numbers $k_1 < k_2  <k_3 < \cdots$ with $\beta_{k_j} > 2^{j}$. Put $\alpha_{k_j} = \frac 1 {\beta_{k_j}}$ for all $j \in \mathbb N$ and $\alpha_k = 0$ if $k \neq k_j$ for any $j$. Then $$\sum^\infty_{k=1} \alpha_k \beta_k = \sum^\infty_{j=1} \alpha_{k_j}\beta_{k_j} = \sum^\infty_{j=1} 1 = \infty$$ but $$\sum^\infty_{k=1} \alpha_k = \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \alpha_{k_j} = \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \frac{1}{\beta_{k_j}} \le \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \frac{1}{2^j} = 1.$$